# Need Expert Advice on Azure Function App V2 and CI/CD Pipeline Best Practices

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, lambda, azure-functions

We're in the midst of developing a B2B SaaS application focusing on procurement services and analytics. We've designed our architecture to be robust, leveraging Azure AD B2C custom policies for user authentication, Azure API Management (APIM) for JWT validation, and Python-based Azure Function App V2 model for our backend API.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywSTH.jpg)
We're satisfied with our architectural choices but have two specific challenges that we'd love your input on:

**Azure Function App V2 and the Blueprint Concept**
We've opted for the Function App V2 model due to its decorator-based route and function registration features. We're currently unsure whether the Blueprint concept from the V1 model is still applicable in the V2 model, and any guidance on this would be invaluable.

**CI/CD Pipeline Best Practices**
We've gleaned much from existing tutorials on setting up CI/CD pipelines for Azure Functions and APIM. Still, we're seeking targeted advice on constructing a CI/CD pipeline that suits our application's unique requirements.
**
Specific Questions:**

- Is the Blueprint concept from the Azure Function App V1 model relevant for the V2 model? If so, how can it be implemented?
- What are the best practices for building a CI/CD pipeline specific to a Python-based Azure Function App V2 model?

We would greatly appreciate your insights and suggestions. Your expertise could be pivotal in enhancing our application's robustness and maintainability.

Looking forward to your responses!

Python-based Azure Function App V2 model with SQL Alchemy for our backend API.

Answer (score 2):

> - Is the Blueprint concept from the Azure Function App V1 model relevant for the V2 model? If so, how can it be implemented?

Yes, The Blueprint concept of Azure Functions python v1 model is relevant in python v2 model as well. As Python v2 model supports  blueprint, Refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,application-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#blueprints)- [A new model called a blueprint is created and used to register functions outside of the main function application. The function runtime does not immediately index the functions registered in blueprint instances. The function app must register the functions from blueprint instances in order to get these blueprint functions indexed.]

*From above [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,application-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#blueprints)*

**My sidblueprint.py:-**

```py
import logging 

import azure.functions as func 

bp = func.Blueprint() 

@bp.route(route="default_template") 
def default_template(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse: 
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.') 

    name = req.params.get('name') 
    if not name: 
        try: 
            req_body = req.get_json() 
        except ValueError: 
            pass 
        else: 
            name = req_body.get('name') 

    if name: 
        return func.HttpResponse( 
            f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP-triggered function " 
            f"executed successfully.") 
    else: 
        return func.HttpResponse( 
            "This HTTP-triggered function executed successfully. " 
            "Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a" 
            " personalized response.", 
            status_code=200 
        )
```

**My function_app.py:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func 
from sidblueprint import bp

app = func.FunctionApp() 

app.register_functions(bp)
```

> - What are the best practices for building a CI/CD pipeline specific to a Python-based Azure Function App V2 model?

You can make use of the AzureFunctionApp@1 or AzureFunctionApp@2 task to deploy your function v2 triggers the same way you deploy Python v1 triggers. Reference [**here**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops.md). But there's one limitation while deploying Azure Python Functions V2. Whenever you deploy Azure Functions python with v2 model the Function is not visible on Portal, There are certain settings and steps that you need to follow according to this **[github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1262#)** raised by me on the same limitations refer below:-

- Add AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags:EnableWorkerIndexing in your Function app configuration.
- Deploy your Function app in Dedicated plan rather than a Consumption based plan.
- Install all your custom packages via venv and deploy your Function in the Function app.
- > I had to remove any code in my `function_app.py` file and  `blueprint.py` file that was above my function definition, apart from imports and initializing the FunctionApp or Blueprint objects. I had variables declared above my function definition in my `blueprint.py` file. Moving those statements to within the function allowed Azure to detect the function when deployed to the cloud.  By
  > **robmitchellzone**
- [Comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1262#issuecomment-1725056727) by **Patrick Loeffler**

For  Deploying my Python Function with blueprint method, I have used the default yaml code in my azure pipeline like below:-

[image]

**My Function app yaml script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxb640-xxxx2a5f'

  
  functionAppName: 'valleyfunc65'

  
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]