# AttributeError: module 'azure.durable_functions' has no attribute 'BluePrint'

Tags: azure, pip, attributeerror, azure-durable-functions, requirements.txt

```
import azure.durable_functions as df
bp_chat = df.BluePrint()
```

**Exception: AttributeError: module 'azure.durable_functions' has no attribute 'BluePrint'**

Now the latest version of azure.durable_functions is 1.2.6, I tried with it and 1.2.3 too. But neither of them works.

I use BluePrint to use my code in an other python file, it is not working without it

I want to run my function_app.py, without errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed with 1.2.0 and it is sure that it does not contains the BluePrint.

But in the 1.2.3 version I found this class in this path
azure.durable_functions.decorators.durable_app.BluePrint()

I realized that pip is not updated the module properly.
I deleted the pip env and I tried again with

```
pip install azure-functions-durable==1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77183417/need-expert-advice-on-azure-function-app-v2-and-ci-cd-pipeline-best-practices/77184875#77184875) to work with blueprint in Azure Functions.

Blueprint method is not part of **azure.durable_functions** in order for blueprint to work, Create 2 files as per this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,application-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#blueprints)

**My function_app.py:-**

```py
import azure.functions as func 
from sidblueprint import bp

app = func.FunctionApp() 

app.register_functions(bp)
```

**My blueprint.py which is calling the blueprint object from function_app.py:-**

```py
import logging 

import azure.functions as func 

bp = func.Blueprint() 

@bp.route(route="default_template") 
def default_template(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse: 
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.') 

    name = req.params.get('name') 
    if not name: 
        try: 
            req_body = req.get_json() 
        except ValueError: 
            pass 
        else: 
            name = req_body.get('name') 

    if name: 
        return func.HttpResponse( 
            f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP-triggered function " 
            f"executed successfully.") 
    else: 
        return func.HttpResponse( 
            "This HTTP-triggered function executed successfully. " 
            "Pass a name in query or body" 
            " personalized response.", 
            status_code=200 
        )
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

If you want to use blueprint pip module, Directly install it by referring [here](https://pypi.org/project/blueprint/)