# Deploying multiple functions to same function app

Tags: python, azure, function, esb

I'm trying to publish 2 functions to my Azure function app, "copy-read-from-esb".

Everything is written in Python in VS Code. The problem is that it looks like it will only register in my function app if the name of the Python file is `function_app.py`. But as I have 2, they cannot have the same name, and the one that is not called `function_app.py` will not register in my function app.

It looks like Azure functions use a `function.json` file, but I'm not certain how this works, nor if that only applies to C#.

I tried publishing through my CLI `func azure functionapp publish ..`, and although this seems to work, I can only add one `.py` file because the required naming convention is somehow set to `function__app.py`.

Comment: You need to add both your functions in the same function_app.py, Then deploy the it to the Function app

Comment: Refer my SO answer here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506062/is-it-possible-to-have-folders-in-v2-python-azure-functions/77514766#77514766

Answer (score 1):

You need to add both the Functions in the same **`function_app.py`** file or you can create a **`blueprint file`** and call all your Function triggers from there.

Refer my [SO answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506062/is-it-possible-to-have-folders-in-v2-python-azure-functions/77514766#77514766) to run 2 functions in **`function_app.py`** and [SO answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77263215/attributeerror-module-azure-durable-functions-has-no-attribute-blueprint/77263429#77263429) for **blueprint implemantation**.

[image]

I created 2 functions and added them in function_app.py:-

**`function_app.py:-`**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )



@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

***Commands to deploy the Function via CLI:-***

```bash
az login
az account set --subscription "SubscriptionName"
func azure functionapp publish siliconfunc5
```

**Output:-**

Both the Function Triggers got deployed successfully with function core tools command above.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, just to test quickly I added the function to the function_app.py:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Looks like the both find the functionapp after publishing. But It seems they cant find the connectionstring, although referenced in the app settings.

AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags is set to : EnableWorkerIndexing.

Comment: For [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121), do not post images of code. Please update your answer and add the relevant code into codeblocks. Thanks